# Get Input value in the same row jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a table with 3 td in the same row with an input text.

```
| Val1 | Val2 | Val3 |
| ---- | ---- | ---- |
| input val fixed | input var call blur | input result
| input val fixed | input var call blur | input result
| input val fixed | input var call blur | input result
| input val fixed | input var call blur | input result
```

The first td has a fixed value, the second variable and the third is the result of an operation.

I'm trying to get the first value with the blur in the second field, but it's returning me undefined.

I´ve tried with 3 ways but all returned "undefined"

Attempt 1 -- undefined

```
let tr      = $(this).closest('tr')
let value1  = tr.find("td:eq(0) input[type='text']").val()
```

Attempt 2 -- undefined

```
var value1 = $(".valFixed",$(this).parent().parent()).val()
```

Attempt 3 -- undefined

```
var value1 = $(this).parent().parent().find("input:eq(0)").val();
```

Can someone please tell me what's wrong?

Comment: Please revise to show actual HTML and put your script in a working snipping using the editor. We don't really do hypotheticals here. See [ask].

Comment: Attempt one looks correct, but it's hard to say without seeing your actual situation.

Comment: Here is the fiddle to exemplify the problem 
https://jsfiddle.net/urtae1cx/

Answer (score 1):

Using Jquery I did what you needed. I added a multiplying function just as a test to see if I could get all the values. onkeyup calls the function every time a key is pressed.

```js
function show(value, num)
{
  console.log(value)
  multiplying(value, num);
}

function multiplying(mvalue, mnum) {
  if(mvalue === '') $('#result'+mnum).val('');
  else {
    parseInt(mvalue);
    $('#result'+mnum).val(parseInt($('#val'+mnum).val())*mvalue);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="val0" value="2">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" onkeyup="show(this.value, 0)">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="result0" readonly>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="val1" value="3">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" onkeyup="show(this.value, 1)">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="result1" readonly>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="val2" value="4">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" onkeyup="show(this.value, 2)">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="result2" readonly>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @SillasSenna I really liked your solution and I'll keep it here for the next opportunity.
But, I have a lot of fields to adjust. I posted a solution there in the answers I was able to do

Answer (score 1):

I have a table with over 200 fields to adjust.

For that, after being hit hard, I came up with this solution

**Table**

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
    <input type="text" value="2">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" name="teste" onblur="calc(this)">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text">
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <input type="text" value="3">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" onblur="calc(this)">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text">
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <input type="text" value="4">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" onblur="calc(this)">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text">
  </td>
</tr>


</table>
```

**Script**

```
function calc(elem)
                {
                    let valFix  = ($(elem).closest('tr').find('td').eq(0).find('input').val());
                    let valCal  = ($(elem).val());
                    var calcVal = (valFix * valCal).toFixed(2);

                    ($(elem).closest('tr').find('td').eq(2).find('input').val(calcVal))

                }
```

**Fiddle**
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0ukm8gfo/)

Hope it helps someone too.